# Non integral exponent for taylor expansion using sage

Tags: taylor-expansion, sagemath

This is my function

```
var('h,r')
f=r^2*arccos((r-h)/r)-(r-h)*sqrt(2*r*h-h^2)

taylor(f,h,0,3)
```

Result:

```
-1/5*sqrt(2)*h^(5/2)/sqrt(r) + 4/3*sqrt(2)*h^(3/2)*sqrt(r)
```

I expected an expression of the form ax^3+bx^2+cx+d but I got 5/2 and 3/2 as exponents for h. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a plot from -1 to 1 of the function for $r=3$.

[image: This is a plot]

Notice, like `sqrt`, it doesn't continue beyond zero.  Indeed, the [complex plot](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=ibwpqc) makes it clear there is a branch cut in the usual implementation, which would indicate $h=0$ is a 'bad point', presumably then also not analytic and not capable of being expanded as a (Taylor) series. Apparently in this case (I'm too lazy to check), like `sqrt`, it isn't even a pole or it would have a Laurent expansion.

See [this math.SX question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122038/definition-of-an-algebraic-singularity) for details which I found quite interesting - that there was a name for a 'branch point' as opposed to other singularity types was not emphasized when I learned complex analysis lo these many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $$\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{r-h}{r}\right)=\cos ^{-1}(1-x)=\sqrt{2} \sqrt{x}+\frac{x^{3/2}}{6 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{3 x^{5/2}}{80
   \sqrt{2}}+O\left(x^{7/2}\right)$$ where $x=\frac hr$.

On the other hand, rewrite $$\sqrt{2rh-h^2}=\sqrt{2rh}\sqrt{1-\frac{h}{2r}}=\sqrt{2rh}\sqrt{1-y}=\sqrt{2rh}\Big(1-\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{8}-\frac{y^3}{16}+O\left(y^4\right)\Big)$$ where $y=\frac {h}{2r}$.

Replace $x$ and $y$ by their definition and you will see how appear powers $3/2$ and $5/2$.

Comment: I think the question is whether this is a *Taylor* series, not something like a Puiseux series.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288164/non-integral-exponent-for-taylor-expansion-using-sage as a dup also.

Comment: @kcrisman I executed a command to get the taylor series and got something that looked like Puisseux which does not interrest me. The equation represents the area under the chord of a circle in terms of the radius of the circle and the height h of the chord. I have been told that we cannot solve this transcendental equation. I would like to avoid calculating h in terms of  the area A under the chord numerically. I thought of getting the taylor series and solving the polynomial equation although I am aware it would not be the closed form of the original equation.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288164/ states that it is a bug.